# How To check if zipfile already has been downloaded

Tags: delphi

I have made a Delphi application which downloads a zipfile (update.zip) at a regular interval. In the zipfiles there are DLL and Exe. 
The zipfile is unzipped and the DLLs and Exes are copied to the correct folder.

What I want to Know is how can I know if the zipfile has been downloaded by the client so it doesn't have to download it again. Because it has already been processed by the client. But when the contents of the zipfile has changed then
it must download the zipfile again.

The contents of the zipfiles can change if we build a new DLL or Exe. But the name of the zipfile is the Same.

Comment: So you want to know if your zip filce contains an exe/dll with a certain version number

Comment: Well, remember if you already did it, and don't do it again if you did

Comment: And which Zip library are you using?

Comment: i'm using KaZip Library

Comment: david, i don't understand what you mean?

Comment: So you want to know if your zip filce contains an exe/dll with a certain version number?

Comment: if the file is changed by your code, download the file again when you change it - if the app which changes the file is not under your control, monitor the file size and download it again when it changes

Comment: What I mean is when you download the file, note its version. Only download again when a different version is available.

Comment: How do you download it? Do you have control of that server? Consider writing a web service which will receive the client version information and will response as needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know whether the zip file has changed without downloading the zip file, then your server will have to provide some other way for you to discover what versions of DLLs and EXEs are on the server. That could be as simple as keeping a text file on the server. Download that file instead of the whole zip file. If the versions in that text file are newer than the versions you have locally, then download the zip file.

You can also avoid processing the zip file by deleting it after you've processed it the first time. Instead of comparing versions in the text file with versions of files in the local zip file, you can compare the text-file versions with the versions of the actual files on disk.

Answer (score 0):

you could do a HTTP HEAD; and check the file last-modified date on server and local if changed download the new file.

```pas
uses
......, IdHTTP;
function getHTTPLastModified(url: string): TDateTime;
var
  HTTP: TIdHTTP;
begin
  try
    try
      HTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
      HTTP.Head( url );
      result:=HTTP.Response.LastModified;
    except
      on E: Exception do
         //ShowMessage('ProcessHttpRequest failed.');
         result := 0;
    end;
  finally
    try
      HTTP.Disconnect;
    except
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Hi shobits1, Could you give me a example code how to do this

Comment: This highly depends on the server. Many web servers don't provide this ability. On top of that, reading the last-modified date of files isn't always guaranteed either. This can be overwritten.

Comment: @user It seems like you want us to write your program for you

Comment: David, No that's not.

Comment: If you are going to use the `Last-Modified` header, then save its value **as-is** with the file, do not interpret it in any way.  Include the value **as-is** in the `If-Modified-Since` header of subsequent requests. If the file has not changed since the last download, the server will return a `304 Not Modified` response with no file data, otherwise it will send a `200 OK` response with the new file data.

Comment: A more reliable solution is to use the [`ETag`](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-14.19) header instead. `ETag` was designed for detecting content changes. Save the `ETag` that is reported on a download, then include it in the `If-None-Match` header of subsequent requests. If the file has not changed since the last download, its `ETag` will not have changed yet, and the server will report a `304 Not Modified` response with no file data, otherwise it will send a `200 OK` response with the new file data and latest `ETag` value.